# disable IE specific gradient properties in less

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

While using, [.gradient in less](http://lesshat.com/#gradient), I've tried the "false" toogle within lesshat.less under:

```
  // Config supported browsers for your project
    @ms: false;  // IE 10+
```

but I still get the SVG gradient.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the change must be done under the .gradient instructions:

> .gradient(...){
>
> ```
>   //  Local config for disabling properties
>
>   @svg: false; //  SVG gradient for IE9
> ```